# Solved this problem using binomial distribution. How do I approximate it to Poisson?

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

Bob and Tim have a 2000 Ford Taurus. Every time they drive it, the car breaks down with probability 1/10.

What is the probability that the car breaks down at most one time in the first 50 drives? Compute the probability using Binomial Distribution and also approximate it using a Poisson distribution. Justify the approximation and compare the results.

I've solved this equation using a Binomial Distribution.

My solution:
${50 \choose 1} 0.1^1 (0.9)^{49} = 2.86$%

Now how the hecksies do I approximate this using Poisson Distribution?
For instance, I have no idea what $\lambda$ would be because there's no rate lol

Answer (score 1):

First, note that the question is asking about at most one time. Hence you should compute $P(X \le 1)$ rather than $P(X=1)$.

To use Poisson distribution, estimate $\lambda$ as $np$. That is choose it to share the same mean as the binomial distribution.

Comment: Ah good catch. So this would be the correct answer?
${50 \choose 2} 0.1^2 (0.9)^{48} = 7.79$%

Comment: You are using the formula for $P(X=2)$, hence that is not correct. You should compute $P(X=0)+P(X=1)$.

Comment: ${50 \choose 1} 0.1^1 (0.9)^{49} + {50 \choose 0} 0.1^0 (0.9)^{50} = 2.91$%.

Comment: If the question asks if most $n$ times, there must be an easier way than adding $P(X = 0) + \dots + P(X = N)$ to get the answer right?

Comment: not really, it can be represented as incomplete gamma function. you might like to read more at the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) page.